# Встроить свой скрипт в макет на wix

Tags: wix

На платформе (конструктор сайтов) wix можно добавлять только встроенные виджеты и т.п., и ещё ограниченный набор функционала, а вот встроить свой скрипт, или как-то использовать сторонний (например, чтобы встроить комментарии из вк или что-то подобное) как я понял, нельзя. 
Есть ли возможность все таки этого добиться, или лучше найти аналог сервиса, где будет такая возможность?

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете вставить Javascript код с помощью приложения HTML. Однако, обратите внимание, что этот код будет работать только учитывая ограничения виджета HTML.

Чтобы добавить код HTML:

- Слева в редакторе нажмите Добавить .
- Нажмите Еще.
- Кликните по приложению HTML-код или перетащите его на страницу.
- Нажмите Вставить код.
- Добавьте ваш код.
- Нажмите Обновить.

Answer (score 0):

Можно установить приложение Google Tag Manager в разделе [Инструменты маркетинга](https://www.wix.com/my-account/site-selector/?buttonText=Manage%20Integrations&title=Select%20a%20Site&autoSelectOnSingleSite=true&actionUrl=https://www.wix.com/dashboard/%7B%7BmetaSiteId%7D%7D/marketing-integration) и в него добавить любой JS код без ограничений.